# Allure reporting versus extent reports in selenium

Tags: selenium, reporting, allure

I am using extent reports in selenium framework but i got suggestion to use Allure reporting. Is anyone using Allure reporting or having idea what is a better choice ?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know a thing about extent reports, but I do love a few things Allure provides. Steps are a great thing (easier bug reproduction) and screenshots on failure are amazing as well. Not sure if extent reports offers that though.

Comment: How can you compare when you have not used both? :)  Both items you say are supported btw in Extent. It also works with ExtentX and soon Maetri to display many analytics.  Project sites:  http://extentx.herokuapp.com, http://allure.qatools.ru, http://extentreports.com.

Comment: one of the things that is interesting to me, is that you can have several tests for one test story which can not be found in extent report.

Comment: I am working on Cucumber - Selenium framework and I am facing similar decision issues. Can anyone answer this question as to which reporting tool is better and why?

Comment: Per personal experience of using both, my vote is for Allure reports. Reasons : more verbose, results at suit level and test level. As suite level - it has graph for status, severity and duration.It has categories, which is product defect and which is test defect. It also marks test flaky if it flaky one. I would recommend to give it a try.